# How to loop a <li> in google script using the spreadsheet data as a menu

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to create a dynamic menu using Google Apps Script. Can you please give me any idea on how to create it. The list of menu will be added by admin and it will store in a spreadsheet.

I've tried to create this code:

```
<div id="side_menubar">
  <ul>
  <? var data = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById('some id')
        .getSheetByName("Menu")
        .getDataRange()
        .getDisplayValues();
     var colA = [0];
     var i = 1;
  ?> 
  <script>
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      $('#side_menubar').append($('<li><?= data[i][colA] ?></li>'))
    }
 </script>
 </ul>    
</div>
```

It should show the list of menu stored in the spreadsheet on the first column. However, my code only shows the first data and loops up to 10 `'li'` with same data.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you cannot create a dynamic menu since there's no built-in way to update the state of the sidebar...

Comment: When your `HtmlTemplate` evaluates, note that the value of variable `colA` is the **`Array`** `[ 0 ]`. That means you're attempting to evaluate `data[i][<Array Object>]`. You probably wanted `var colA = 0`, which would mean `data[i][0]`-- the first element of the `i`-th element of the `data` array.

Comment: So, there's no way I can create a dynamic list of menu? Even I use a loop?

Comment: I have updated the code to this:
<div id="side_menubar">

    <ul>
<? var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id");
var menu = data.getSheetByName("Menu"); 
        var i = 2;        
        ?> 
        <script>
         for(var i = 2; i <= 6; i++){
        $('#side_menubar').append($('<li class="menu"><?= menu.getRange("A" + i).getValues(); ?></li>'))
          }
 </script>
    </ul>    
</div>   - However, the loop is like not working.

Comment: Julius, e.maguire is incorrect. There are plenty of ways. See what tehhowch said.

Comment: Hi TheMaster, I have updated my code before your comment, is there something wrong with that code, the loops is working and it create the number of 'li' required however, the range is not following the number of variable i.

Comment: Hard to read code in the comment.. How about you [edit] your question? Also, I don't recommend scriplets. Load async like [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates) PS:Address people using `@` like  `@TheMaster` or we won't get notifications.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I already figured it out.

Comment: @Julius You can post it as a answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out:

```
<div id="side_menubar">

    <ul>
    <script>

<? var menu = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Some ID")
.getSheetByName("Menu");
        ?> 
        <?for(var i = 2; i <= 20; i++){?>
        $('#side_menubar').append($('<li class="menu"><?= menu.getRange("A" + i).getValues(); ?></li>'))
         <? } ?>
 </script>
    </ul>    
</div>
```